# How do i make my multimedia keys work with Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: lubuntu

I have a Microsoft Digital Media Pro Keyboard, and when i press the Volume + button, nothing happens for example.

I went ahead and installed Keytouch-Editor and mapped all my keys but it does nothing.

Does anyone have a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on a Dell keyboard and on an Asus netbook (yup, old stuff), and editing the file *~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml* like suggested in the following page helped.

https://www.queryxchange.com/q/3_610786/volume-hot-key-not-working-in-lubuntu/

```
<!-- Keybinding for Volume management -->
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
<action name="Execute">
<command>amixer -D pulse sset Master 3%+</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
<action name="Execute">
<command>amixer -D pulse sset Master 3%-</command>
</action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
<action name="Execute">
<command>amixer -D pulse sset Master 0%</command>
</action>
</keybind>
```

After that, used the command *openbox --reconfigure* in the terminal and both keyboards are working fine now.